# Get background color of clicked date

Tags: android, caldroid

I'm using Caldroid and I have a problem with getting background color of clicked date. My listener looks like that:

```
listener = new CaldroidListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
        //HERE I WANT TO CHECK COLOR
    }
};
```

How can I check background color of clicked date in above listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable)view.getBackground()
int color = buttonColor.getColor();
if (color == android.R.color.white) {
    //color is white
}
```

Comment: That does not work for me; I get a "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable"

Comment: May you use Dravable, not color for your background of view. Try check to instanceof:
Drawable buttonColor = view.getBackground()
if(buttonColor instanceof ColorDrawable){
...
}